# Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender (No such User here)

Tags: email, routes, migration, email-validation, mx-record

I have migrated my website and the email records to a new server (other provider). Everything was ok except that now when I want to send a message from my email (my email direction is the same), one of my clients can not receive my messages. I chatted with my client and his mails are ok, he is receiving mails without problems, as he said.
I reported the problem to my Hosting provider and they have changed the mail Exchanger from remote to local but it didn't finish with the problem. Someone knows what could be happening?
This is part of the message that appears:

"

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

    peter@thisismyclientsdirection.com
    No Such User Here
    peter@thisismyclientsotherdirection.com
    No Such User Here

Reporting-MTA: dns; cherry.theserversite.pro

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;peter@thisismyclientsdirection.com
Status: 5.0.0

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;peter@thisismyclientsotherdirection.com
Status: 5.0.0


Return-path: <comercial@mydomain.com>
Received: from [71.13.252.126] (port=58531 helo=[10.145.123.217])
    by cherry.theserversite.pro with esmtpsa  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    (Exim 4.93)
    (envelope-from <comercial@mydomain.com>)
    id 1UZ6w-00EaD5-0h; Mon, 19 Oct 2020 13:38:33 -0400
To: peter@thisismyclientsdirection.com, peter@thisismyclientsotherdirection.com
From: comercial@mydomain.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Reenv=c3=ado_-_cotizaciones_mantenimiento?=

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

Content-Language: es-ES
X-Antivirus: Avast (VPS 201019-2, 19/10/2020), Outbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean
X-Exim-DSN-Information: Due to administrative limits only headers are returned
```

"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that the other websites (the domains of my client) are inside my server and in the Email Routing section (it is in the Cpanel) of those websites, the domains were targeted as "Local server" or not targeted. Despite it, the email server for those domains don't were in my server then the system was confused. I just changed the target to "Remote servers" for both domains (the domains of my client) and the problem disappear.
I hope this explanation could be useful for other developer.
Anyway thank you,
TheJohnny